# Getting the dimensions for some <object> HTML code using PHP

Tags: php, html

I have people inserting video code to be displayed on my website. I want to make sure those videos dimensions don't go over 590 pixels in width.

So for example it they insert a video that's 640 x 385 my script would figure out some new dimensions so that it is only 590 pixels in width (e.g: 590 x 366)... I've got all the maths and ratio stuff worked out, it's just a matter of extracting the height and width from the  and then replacing those with the new dimensions.

Here is a sample of some  code I would need to get the dimensions of. There is also  code below but once I figure how to work out the dimensions of the  I can just duplicate the code for the

```
<object width="640" height="385">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ik6N1TLL2TI&hl=en_US&fs=1"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ik6N1TLL2TI&hl=en_US&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

I've got some code I was helped with in the past which adds a URL to links that don't have a http:// in front of them. I tried to play with the code but couldn't figure it out. If it helps, here's the original code:

```
$content_text = preg_replace('%
    (<a\b[^>]*?href\s*+=\s*+)  # capture first chunk of A tag in group 1
    ("|\'|)                                   # capture HREF attribute delimiter in group 2
    (?!\w++://|/)                        # ensure URL has no scheme nor abs path
    ([^"\' >]++)                         # capture relative URI path in group 3
    \2                                        # match closing delimiter for HREF attribute
    %ix', '$1"' . SITEURL . '/$3"', $content_text);
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably will get raked through the coals for this, as you should use the [HTML DOM parser](http://www.php.net/dom) in PHP. But here is the regex as an "alternate" method.

```
preg_match('~<object.*(width|height)=(.*) (width|height)=(.*)(>|\s)~isU', $contents, $matches);
if (!empty($matches)) {
    $dimensions[strtolower($matches[1])] = str_replace(array("'", '"'), '', $matches[2]);
    $dimensions[strtolower($matches[3])] = str_replace(array("'", '"'), '', $matches[4]);
}
```

The [HTML Parser](http://www.php.net/dom) may be a wiser choice, but the above should grab the width and height no matter the quotes or the order and will place them in `$dimensions['width']` and `$dimensions['height']`.

Like I said, this is just an alternative example and the [HTML Parser](http://www.php.net/dom) is probably the wiser way to go. Also the Regex could probably be written better as well but oh well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Premiso, the HTML Parser was the way to go :) Appreciate your help!